# How to solve paraFOAM compilation error with libQt5Core.so.5.15.2:?

Tags: paraview, openfoam

everyone:

I am using OpenFoam-11 ThirdParty-MakeparaView function to compile ParaView function, but I encountered some problems. I want to ask how to install it successfully?

```
`[100%] Built target NodeEditor
/usr/bin/ld: /home/junius/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.2: undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::_M_release()@CXXABI_1.3.13'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/junius/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.15.2: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_array_new_length()@GLIBCXX_3.4.29'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/junius/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.2: undefined reference to `std::__exception_ptr::exception_ptr::_M_addref()@CXXABI_1.3.13'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Clients/ParaView/CMakeFiles/paraview.dir/build.make:224: bin/paraview] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:33060: Clients/ParaView/CMakeFiles/paraview.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[100%] Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/paraview-5.10/plugins/SaveStateAndScreenshot/SaveStateAndScreenshot.so
[100%] Built target SaveStateAndScreenshot
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
Command exited with non-zero status 2
6787.28user 668.55system 15:42.63elapsed 790%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3421208maxresident)k
0inputs+5884672outputs (255major+262579343minor)pagefaults 0swaps`
```

I am a Linux novice, so if possible, please answer in more detail. I would greatly appreciate your help！
Best Regards,

I tried to specify the qmake_path in the compilation path as the downloaded QT5_Default path,

```
`#!/bin/sh
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# =========                 |
# \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
#  \\    /   O peration     |
#   \\  /    A nd           | Copyright (C) 2011-2017 OpenFOAM Foundation
#    \\/     M anipulation  |
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# License
#     This file is part of OpenFOAM.
#
#     OpenFOAM is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#     under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#     the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#     (at your option) any later version.
#
#     OpenFOAM is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
#     ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
#     for more details.
#
#     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#     along with OpenFOAM.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# Script
#     makeParaView
#
# Description
#     Make and install paraview 4 or 5
#     - place the paraview source under $WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR/ParaView-VERSION
#       (note capitalisation)
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# run from third-party directory only
cd ${0%/*} || exit 1
wmakeCheckPwd "$WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR" || {
    echo "Error: Current directory is not \$WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR"
    echo "    The environment variables are inconsistent with the installation."
    echo "    Check the OpenFOAM entries in your dot-files and source them."
    exit 1
}
. etc/tools/ThirdPartyFunctions
. etc/tools/ParaViewFunctions
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# USER OPTIONS:
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# MPI support:
withMPI=false
MPI_MAX_PROCS=32

# Python support:
# note: script will try to determine the appropriate python library.
#       If it fails, specify the path using the PYTHON_LIBRARY variable
withPYTHON=false
PYTHON_LIBRARY=""
PYTHON_INCLUDE=""
# Examples
# PYTHON_LIBRARY="/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0"
# PYTHON_INCLUDE="/usr/include/python2.7"

# OSMESA graphics support:
withOSMESA=false
OSMESA_INCLUDE="/usr/include/GL"
OSMESA_LIBRARY="/usr/lib64/libOSMesa.so"

# extra QT gui support (useful for some third party apps)
withQT=true

# Set the path to the Qt-4.7 (or later) qmake if the system Qt is older
QMAKE_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5"

# Set the path to cmake
CMAKE_PATH=""`
`
```

but it seems that there is no help. In the final stage of the compilation, I still think that I use Anaconda's Qt. When I tried to disable ANACONDA in Bashrc, compiling the sameOut of the wrong, I don't know how to do it.